# Android Login with php getting error after successful json parsing

Tags: android, json

Hi i am getting an error even if login with correct user name and password.but json response is correct but it is showing user not found.where i need to change the code. Thanks in advance.
i am getting success json data if i login with correct user name and password else failure response i am getting but every time it is showing user not found error.

```
 Login extends Activity {
        Button b;
        EditText et,pass;
        TextView tv;
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        HttpPost httppost;
        StringBuffer buffer;
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        HttpResponse response;
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        HttpClient httpclient;
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs;
        ProgressDialog dialog = null;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.login);

            b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button01);  
            et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
            pass= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
            tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);

            b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    dialog = ProgressDialog.show(Login.this, "", 
                            "Validating user...", true);
                     new Thread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                login();                          
                            }
                          }).start();               
                }
            });
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        void login(){
            try{            

                httpclient=new DefaultHttpClient();
                httppost= new HttpPost("http://192.168.137.224/android_connect/get_product_details.php"); // make sure the url is correct.
                //add your data
                nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                // Always use the same variable name for posting i.e the android side variable name and php side variable name should be similar, 
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name",et.getText().toString().trim()));  // $Edittext_value = $_POST['Edittext_value'];
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",pass.getText().toString().trim())); 
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                //Execute HTTP Post Request
                response=httpclient.execute(httppost);
                // edited by James from coderzheaven.. from here....
                ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
                final String response = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);
                System.out.println("Response : " + response); 
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
    //                    tv.setText("Response from PHP : " + response);
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                if(response.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) 
                {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(Login.this,"Login Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });

                    startActivity(new Intent(Login.this, OtherActivty.class));
                }else{
                    showAlert();                
                }

            }catch(Exception e){
                dialog.dismiss();
                System.out.println("Exception : " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        public void showAlert(){
            Login.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Login.this);
                    builder.setTitle("Login Error.");
                    builder.setMessage("User not Found.")  
                           .setCancelable(false)
                           .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                               }
                           });                     
                    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                    alert.show();               
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is in the response variable, post the value.

Comment: yes is the response variable

Comment: Well, if all the code is like you posted it, then it is not. It is just not possible.

Comment: You said you are getting JSON from the server. yes is not JSON

Comment: i have posted every thing...

Comment: tell me what you get from this, just copy the output! System.out.println("Response : " + response);

Comment: ["success"] = yes;
["message"] = "You have been sucessfully login";  this i am getting

Comment: finally i got solution.

Comment: if(response.contains("success"))

Comment: That is really bad, see my answer!

Comment: I just wanted to say that it is bad practice to do things like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/java-json/java-json.jar.zip as a library!

First of all, the JSON is not proper!

Proper JSON:
{
    "success": "yes",
    "message": "Logged In"
}

Second use this to retrieve the contents of the "success" variable:

```
    JSONObject myjson = new JSONObject(response);
    System.out.println(myjson.getString("success"));
```

Comment: can you please elaborate your answer and post your answer please